# Compare Apache Settings on Different Machines?

Tags: apache, macos

Is there a way to easily compare the Apache settings for two machines? I have a MacBook Air and an iMac, both running 10.9.1. On both machines, I am trying to run a site via localhost.

~/Sites/foo.loc

On the MacBook Air, the site runs as expected.

On the iMac, the site gives me a 403 Forbidden message.

There is no difference between the two sites.

I am using VirtualHostX 4.2.1 to load the site via http://foo.loc/ and both machines are using the built-in Apache.

**UPDATE:**

Found the apachectl configtest command and it's giving me two error messages on the iMac:

```
Syntax error on line 15 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf: 
Syntax error on line 472 of /private/etc/apache2/users/httpd.conf:
```

Each repeated at least 58 times.

Looked at both lines and nothing stands out. One line points the system to the other.

**UPDATE NO. 2**

Line 471 and 472 from /private/etc/apache2/users/httpd.conf

```
# User home directories
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

And complete contents of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

```
# Settings for user home directories
#
# Required module: mod_userdir

#
# UserDir: The name of the directory that is appended onto a user's home
# directory if a ~user request is received.  Note that you must also set
# the default access control for these directories, as in the example below.
#
UserDir Sites

#
# Users might not be in /Users/*/Sites, so use user-specific config files.
#
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
<IfModule bonjour_module>
       RegisterUserSite customized-users
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE NO. 3**

And here's the contents of bseymore.conf, the only .conf file in /users/

```
<Directory "/Users/bseymore/Sites/">
  Options Indexes MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Can you copy the config from the MBA to the iMac and retry?

Comment: Can you post line 472 of httpd.conf and the entire httpd-userdir.conf if it's not too long?

Comment: Updated the original question with those, along with the contents of that /users/bseymore.conf files.

Comment: Patrix: Which config file should I copy? httpd.conf seems to be in a couple different places.